# QField sync error message

Tags: python, qfield

When using QField sync I get the following error message but I'm a GIS novice and cannot make out where the problem lies.

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

> IndexError: list index out of range
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\core\offline_converter.py", line 381, in on_offline_editing_next_layer
> msg = self.trUtf8('Packaging layer {layer_name}…').format(layer_name=self.__offline_layer_names[layer_index - 1])
> IndexError: list index out of range

Python version: `3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]`
QGIS version: `3.16.8-Hannover Hannover, 8c50902e`

Python Path:

```
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS31~1.8/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS31~1.8/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.8\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.8\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.8\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.8\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.8\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.8\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.8\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.8\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.8\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\DigitizingTools\tools
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\DigitizingTools
C:/Users/User/Documents/Qfield_import
```

I initially used an older version (3.10) but using this version doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you let us know which version of the QFieldSync plugin you have installed?

Comment: Another message I get is "the data has been synchronized successfully but the original project could not be opened"

Comment: If I try to save the project & close "unable to perform zip" appears. I had hoped that saving, closing and then reopening the project would solve the issue

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn I have the 3.4.4 plugin installed. When I open what I think is the original project & sync

Comment: Can you install https://github.com/opengisch/qfieldsync/releases/download/v4.0.0-beta7/qfieldsync.v4.0.0-beta7.zip (as zip file from the plugin manager)?

Comment: My apologies, I should have said I reverted to the older version of QGIS (3.10) again as I kept getting messages about incompatibility. That QField sync release will not work with this version...I tried..

Comment: Is it possible to sync the data without using the plugin?

Comment: https://qfield.cloud/

Comment: My project was created on QGIS 3.10, if I reinstall 3.16 and try to open & sync the project on this version with the experimental plugin version could that work? I'm sorry about the questions, I'm a bit of a novice & the project is urgent.

Comment: Yes it "could work", QGIS 3.10 is certainly no longer supported. If it's urgent you can also consider to get professional support.